# Наиболее эффективный код парсинга строки в целое число

Tags: java, соревнование

Часто приходится пАрсить строку в целое число, типа:

```
public static int string2Int(String s, int defaultValue) {
    int i=defaultValue;
    try {
        i=Integer.parseInt(s);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
    }
    return i;
}
```

Код хорош всем, за исключением, того, что `Exception`, как известно, *дорогой* процесс.

**Так вот вопрос:** кто предложит наиболее эффективный (в смысле ресурсов и скорости) способ парсинга строки в `int`? Строка содержит число в десятичном исчислении (никаких *hex/bin/octal*) - возможно и отрицательное. Если строка содержит дробное число, то дробная часть откидывается.

**Условия:** метод принимает 2 параметра: строка и значение по умолчанию - никаких `Exception` не выкидывается. При ошибке парсинга возвращается значение по умолчанию.

**Update**

В итоге есть 3 способа, условно классический (в самом вопросе), метод прямого парсинга в инкарнации @АртемКоновалов и удаленный способ через Apache Commons предложенный @LiashenkoV.

Я составил небольшой тест, который генерирует 50 тыс. случайных строк, 1/3 строка типа `int`, 1/3 строка `double`, 1/3 строка портится внесением случайных символов. Получились следующие цифры:

```
ClassicParser - 300 мс.
ArtemParser - 100 мс.
ApacheParser - 200 мс.
```

Comment: Как планируете сравнивать эффективность?

Comment: parse давно проигрывает по производительности valueOf

Comment: @ДмитрийАлександрович на девятке вот так: `public static Integer valueOf(String s) throws NumberFormatException { return parseInt(s, 10); }`

Comment: Прогоню тест на случайном наборе из 10 тыс. чисел, из которых половина будут неверные

Comment: Комментарий к удаленному сообщению: Apache Commons нормальный вариант, почему бы и нет. Правда изучение исходников приводит к печальным размышлениям (по эффективности кода разумеется).

Comment: Способ тестирования должен быть открыт и содержаться в вопросе, чтобы каждый участник мог определить улучшит или ухудшит результат очередное изменение кода

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Получилось такое решение:

```
public static long getNumber(String value, long defaultValue) {
    if (value == null)
        return defaultValue;

    value = value.trim();
    if (value.length() == 0)
        return defaultValue;

    final char[] chars = value.toCharArray();
    final char delimiter = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().getDecimalSeparator();

    final boolean isNegative;
    if (chars[0] == '-' || chars[0] == '+') {
        if (chars.length == 1 || chars[1] == delimiter)
            return defaultValue;
        else
            isNegative = chars[0] == '-';
    } else if (isDigit(chars[0]))
        isNegative = false;
    else
        return defaultValue;


    final int radix = 10;
    boolean isFloat = false;
    long result = 0;

    for (int i = isDigit(chars[0]) ? 0 : 1; i < chars.length; i++) {
        char currentSymbol = chars[i];
        if (currentSymbol == delimiter)
            if (isFloat)
                return defaultValue;
            else
                isFloat = true;

        if (currentSymbol != delimiter && !isDigit(currentSymbol))
            return defaultValue;

        if (!isFloat) {
            long intermediateResult = result * radix + parse(currentSymbol);
            if (isOverflow(result, intermediateResult))
                return defaultValue;
            else
                result = intermediateResult;
        }
    }

    return isNegative ? -result : result;
}

private static boolean isOverflow(long prev, long current) {
    return prev != 0 && Math.signum(prev) != Math.signum(current);
}

private static boolean isDigit(char symbol) {
    return '0' <= symbol && symbol <= '9';
}

private static int parse(char symbol) {
    return symbol - '0';
}
```

Тест:

```
@Test
public void test() {
    final int defaultValue = 10;
    assertEquals(0, getNumber("0", 10));
    assertEquals(1, getNumber("1", 10));
    assertEquals(-1, getNumber("-1", 10));
    assertEquals(420, getNumber("0420", defaultValue));
    assertEquals(142, getNumber("142", defaultValue));
    assertEquals(-72, getNumber("-72", defaultValue));
    assertEquals(19, getNumber("+19", defaultValue));
    assertEquals(-19, getNumber("-19.11", defaultValue));
    assertEquals(19, getNumber("+19.16", defaultValue));
    assertEquals(defaultValue, getNumber("+19+.16", defaultValue));
    assertEquals(defaultValue, getNumber("+1.9+16", defaultValue));
    assertEquals(defaultValue, getNumber("1.1.16", defaultValue));
    assertEquals(defaultValue, getNumber("+.", defaultValue));
    assertEquals(defaultValue, getNumber(".", defaultValue));
    assertEquals(defaultValue, getNumber("+.0", defaultValue));
    assertEquals(defaultValue, getNumber(Long.MAX_VALUE + "0", 10));
    assertEquals(defaultValue, getNumber(Long.MIN_VALUE + "0", 10));
}
```

Comment: 1. Переполнение. 2. По условию допускается также наличие плавающей точки.

Comment: Хорошая попытка. Только вначале вставьте что-то типа `s.trim()`, чтобы обрезать незначащие пробелы

Comment: спасибо за комментарии  - внес исправления

Comment: Если я правильно понимаю код, с переполнением вопрос не решен, что будет если передать строку `"11111111111111111111"`? Ну и непонятно что возвращать при передаче строки `"+."` - 0 как у вас или default

Comment: `currentSymbol != '.'` - не комильфо, десятичная точка зависит от локали

Comment: @Barmaley эм, уточните тогда в вопросе какие именно бывают разделители, а то это не особо то это очевидно.

Comment: Официально есть 2 разделителя `.` и `,`, но еще неофициально есть парочка разделителей (типа `:`). В терминах Java надо использовать из `DecimalFormatSymbols.getDecimalSeparator()`

Comment: @Barmaley, в общем, сомнительная затея довольно. Что здесь будет кроме этого одного ответа, который учтет все нюансы парсинга? И то если автор не плюнет на эту затею. Вы когда готовились к проведению этого соревнования какие еще рассматривали способы парсинга и рассматривали ли вообще? И есть ли еще другие способы?

Comment: Ответ с **Apache Commons** был хорош, но @LiashenkoV сам его удалил